# How could my PHP and MySQL servers generate different hashes when using SHA1()?

Tags: php, mysql

When I generate an unsalted hash with SHA1 in PHP it is different than when I let my MySQL server handle it. Why is this?

Is there any way I can fix this so the hashes are the same? I'm guessing it's too late if the hashes have already been generated?

```
<?php
$p = 'password';

$p2 = SHA1('$p');

...INSERT INTO table (pass1, pass2) VALUES (SHA1('$p'), '$p2')...


?>
```

EDIT:

It looks like it is hashing "sha1('$p')" instead of the password.

EDIT2:

And I'm an idiot. I put '' in the SHA1. Oops!

Sorry for wasting your time

Comment: Post the two differing hashes.

Comment: Hmmmm I just created a new password and it was hashed the same. I'm going to look into this a bit further.

Comment: There is probably a slight variation in input, so show us _how_ you calculate it, need the code. And yes, even if you find that problem, fixing it without recalculating either all PHP, or all MySQL hashes, is unlikely.

Comment: Oh, and of course, [it just works here](http://pastebin.com/ciLEEZ2j), otherwise I wouldn't ask ;)

Comment: @Jeremy: Which hash is this? Edit the input string and the two output strings into your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code:

```
$p2 = SHA1('$p');
```

Will actually hash the *literal* `$p`, not the *content* of `$p`. You should do:

```
$p2 = SHA1($p);
```

This is because variables and escape sequences are not interpreted by PHP when using single quotes. This is mentioned in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php):

> Note: Unlike the double-quoted and heredoc syntaxes, variables and escape sequences for special characters will not be expanded when they occur in single quoted strings.

Answer (score 1):

It might be the character set that PHP uses for SHA1 encoding.  If MySQL is using Unicode, but PHP is using ASCII, then there will be different results.

Answer (score 0):

The $raw_output flag in PHP's sha1 function affects the format that the generated hash is returned in.  If it is false, then you'll get a 40 digit hex number as a string out of the function.  If it is set to true, then you'll get a raw binary 20 digit number out instead.  It defaults to false.

http://uk.php.net/sha1